# Graph api get results created more than x hours ago

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using the `graph API` , i can manage to get results for the last 12 hours, with this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page/photos/uploaded?since=unix time
```

But i want to add another field that will only give me results that are *bigger than 5 hours ago and smaller than 12 hours ago*, than means -*no* results from the last 5 hours.

How can i add this restriction ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#time

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#time mentions the counter-part to `since` – it is

> `until`: A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data.